# TYPO3: Skip property mapping for child object

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I have a model named "document" and a model "user". The model "user" is part of the model "document" as a child with an m:n relation.

Further i have a form, where someone can set a new "document". Some properties of "user" are in the form too but not all. Want to skip validations for those who are not in the form. I validate the form by both models.

With something like

```
$this->arguments->getArgument('document')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->skipProperties('title');
```

I can disable the property title from validation and works pretty well. If i replace "title" with "user", "user" will not be validated. Not bad, but the complete child object "user" is removed, so i do not have any data made in the front end for "user" anymore. Bad!

So, i would like not to disable "user" complete but single properties. I have tried with

```
$this->arguments->getArgument('document')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->skipProperties('user.*.firstname');
```

To disable the validation of "firstname" from "user" but it does not work. What do i do wrong?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$mappingConfiguration = $this->arguments->getArgument('document')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
$mappingConfiguration->forProperty('user')
  ->skipProperties('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', …);
```

You can build a whole path with this, so if you have e.g. multiple users, you can use

```
$mappingConfiguration->forProperty('users')
  ->forProperty(*)
  ->skipProperties('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', …);
```

See the [documentation for the property mapper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/4-Property-mapping.html)

Comment: Thank you. I get it work for fields directly from "document" but all the fields who have an relation like 1:n or m:n does not work. No matter how i write it. When i debug it, i see my configuration but it has no effect.

Comment: I think there is a general problem.

$this->arguments->getArgument('document')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->skipProperties('title');

This works, when the model does not validate "NotEmpty".